# Are there any laws that prevent reserving two adjacent seats for one person for a flight with Ryanair?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

Ryanair is very cheap and I can afford to pay for another seat in exchange for a little bit more comfort. I do that sometimes on the train and there are no laws against it as far as I know. On the train I can claim that my wife just went to the toilet and show that I have the ticket for the seat next to me.

In Some countries you can do that on the bus too.

[image]

In fact if my laptop was heavier than 15kg it would be cheaper for me to buy another ticket instead of paying for the laptop as an extra bag

[image]

Comment: Note that Ryanair staff may challenge you for brining exxtra carry on luggage - you'll have to explain that it belongs to the extra seat.

Comment: Curious why you'd need an extra seat for that though, I usually just stuff them in the overhead bin

Comment: @Blackbird57: RyanAir typically allows 10kg with limited size on board, and you need to pay for up to 20kg with much bigger size in the hold. And the luggage can be more expensive than the seat! So if you have 2x10 kg luggage, booking two seats might be cheaper. Anyway, luggage left on the seat is likely illegal for security reasons, but you should be able to leave it in the foot area.

Comment: You have a laptop that weighs 15kg?!

Comment: I feel that the change in the question header, buying to reserving, is doing the question a disservice.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee  I could see the entire backpack for a large gaming laptop hitting going above 10kg easily enough.   A high end 17/18" gaming laptop could hit 5-6kg in and of itself, will have a ~300W power brick that's >1kg (a 2 year old dell model is 1.3), 1.5 - 2kg for the backpack (from looking at a few that are built for 18" models on amazon).  Add a mouse, headset, maybe a good external keyboard; and breaking 10kg is easy.

Comment: As an aside, these sort of systems aren't intended for checking email at a coffee shop (although if I owned one, I'd totally game there a few times just to see people's reactions); but to provide something more portable than a large desktop + external monitor for gaming at LAN parties, etc.  In more staid packaging they do the same on oil rigs and other remote locations where helicopter transport makes the extra size/weight of large desktops prohibitive anywhere they can be avoided.

Comment: Note: there are "official" Special Service Request such as CBBG (Cabine Baggage) or EXST (Extra Seat) on regular airlines for such demands; so it's well-known in the airline world.

Comment: I don't think there are laws against it, but what is the ticket actually for? If the ticket is an entitlement for one individual to travel, and the seats themselves are not ticketed, then buying a second ticket would be useless. I think that's how it is on most trains.

Comment: @bdsl Most trains, except for local services, allow seat reservations. On some long-distance trains in some countries, seat reservations are mandatory.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee I suspect there's actually [something else](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/50882/41775) in that laptop bag.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Outside of an emergency evacuation or similarly dire situation, I cannot think of any reason why a civil authority would ban a person from purchasing multiple seats. After all, it is not uncommon for people to purchase an additional seat to carry items like [musical instruments](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22679) or pets, or because they do not fit into a single seat.

In consideration of this, Ryanair not only explicitly permits such a purchase, but provides a page of [instructions on purchasing an additional seat](https://www.ryanair.com/en/questions/can-i-purchase-an-extra-seat-for-a-large-person/) on its website; while it is listed under purchasing for a "large person," the wording includes extra seats purchased for carrying items:

*Note highlighted section*

> To book an extra seat for comfort go online and select 2 seats the first seat should be booked in the actual passenger's name and the extra seat should be entered as COMFORT SEAT as the Last Name and EXTRA as the first Name. The name EXTRA COMFORT SEAT will then be displayed on the reservation and online boarding pass.
>
> Allocated seating in emergency rows 1,16 and 17 may not be purchased if you have purchased an extra seat for item/comfort.
>
> Please note that all passengers purchasing an extra seat can use online check-in. The same travel document details must be entered for both seats when checking in online. Online check-in is available from 30 days prior up to 2 hours before the scheduled flight departure times if you have purchased allocated seats. If you choose not to purchase an allocated seat check in will only be available from 7 days up to 2 hours prior to each scheduled flight departure. **There is no cabin or checked baggage allowance associated with the purchase of an extra seat.**
>
> Customers who have booked an extra seat for comfort should contact our call centre to ensure that they are allocated seats together.
>
> ** Spanish Resident and Large Family Discount is not applicable on EXTRA seats**

Comment: That's  ripoff that they don't give the extra seat it's luggage.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if someone legally changed his/her name to EXTRA COMFORT SEAT.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen: [something like this](https://xkcd.com/327/) will happen.

Answer (score 9):

You may of course purchase an extra seat for luggage. This is common in a few situations when one cannot be separated from large cargo, the most obvious one being for transportation of musical instruments that are too fragile to go in the hold and too large to go in the cabin as hand luggage.

You cannot keep your laptop on the seat during take off or landing, because of course it is a hazard to have it flying about the cabin during an emergency.

There are no taxes or airport fees due on the second seat so actually it is a lot cheaper than the first seat.

One thing I would say is if you have an empty seat next to you, someone else may think it is free and try to sit in it. So be prepared to stand your ground.

Comment: Luggage on a seat is a hazard even during cruise. If you hit turbulence, it can become a projectile.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Indeed, but it is not specifically forbidden during cruise. Indeed, I am usually working on my laptop during the cruise!

Comment: Working on your laptop is completely different to having it on the seat next to you. Your hands on the keyboard will probably stop it flying through the air.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Absolutely. But I don't think anyone is too worried. Often I put the laptop on the blocked middle seat in Euro business when the meal is served for example. (Not applicable to Ryanair! But it doesn't seem to be disallowed.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Actually musical instruments are strapped to the seat. They are not left loose.