# If I have bought X tickets, do I have X hand baggage allowances?

Tags: air-travel, legal, bookings, hand-luggage

If I have bought 3 tickets for the same flight, can I bring three times the cabin allowance allowed per ticket?

The way I see it I am doing the airline a favor

Related:

[Is it prohibited to lie down (and fall asleep) on a commercial flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60010/is-it-prohibited-to-lie-down-and-fall-asleep-on-a-commercial-flight)

[Are there any laws that prevent reserving two adjacent seats for one person for a flight with Ryanair?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50299/are-there-any-laws-that-prevent-reserving-two-adjacent-seats-for-one-person-for)

Comment: This might be forbidden in some airline policies.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the allowance is *per passenger* on most airlines regardless of the number of tickets you hold. You may be better off buying a business class ticket (they usually come with more generous carry-on limits)

Comment: I am mainly interested in cheap ones like Ryanair and EasyJet

Comment: @Kris the most common reason for buying more seats than people is to transport bulky fragile items, such as large musical instruments, as hand luggage.  Whether the cello gets an allowance for a hand bag of its own seems perhaps irrelevant.  Another reason is to accommodate people who don't fit in a single seat.  I suspect therefore that airlines may have policies thatdepend on the reason the extra ticket was purchased.

Comment: This is going to depend on the airline and possibly even on your fare rules. Please specify them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most European airlines have carry-on baggage allowances *per passenger* not per ticket.

But then again, if you really need that extra baggage on board you can buy a separate seat, such as Ryanair "item seat" option or the extra seat reservation offered by airBaltic. These options are very popular with people having to carry fragile items such as cameras, musical instruments, etc.

The rule of thumb is - if it fits in the overhead baggage compartment, and you can lift it there by yourself, it's allowed.
But if in doubt whether your carry-on baggage will be allowed on board, you can consult the airline prior to the flight.

Comment: I'd potentialy be careful with 'rule of thumb', many carriers impose weight loss limits on hand luggage. Even if not all airlines enforce them all of the time - and it can be costly to have bags checked in at the gate if it turns out to be too heavy.